# How can I query Facebook friends in User using Parse?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse as my database. I want to access the _Users class to see if my Facebook friends are using the app (in the class _User). I have just read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233359/ios-get-parse-facebook-friends-name-and-score) and found out that you can't save friendlist anymore.

The way I did it so far is:

I first get the FB ids of my friends and query it in _User. However, I noticed that the FacebookIDs are saved as authData. How can I query my _User class using FacebookIDs besides creating a new column duplicating facebookIDs as strings?

```
// Send request to Facebook
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        [FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // result will contain an array with your user's friends in the "data" key
                NSArray *friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
                NSMutableArray *friendIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:friendObjects.count];
                // Create a list of friends' Facebook IDs
                for (NSDictionary *friendObject in friendObjects) {
                    [friendIds addObject:[friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
                }
                self.fbfriendList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:friendObjects];

                    PFQuery *friendQuery = [ParseUser query];

//PROBLEM is here where the fbId in my _User class is saved as authData
                    [friendQuery whereKey:@"fbID" containedIn:friendIds];

                    NSArray *friendUsers = [friendQuery findObjects];
                self.fbfriendList = friendObjects;  
            }
        }]; 
    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse Users' Facebook IDs are private by default, but you can make them accessible from other users.

To accomplish this, you can use the Facebook API to get the user's Facebook ID, assign it to a field on the Parse User. Then you can construct a query on the User collection to get a list of Parse users whose Facebook IDs are in your user's friend list.

When you do your Login with Facebook, you should do it like this:

```
// When your user logs in, immediately get and store its Facebook ID
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray
                                block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
  if (user) {
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
        // Store the current user's Facebook ID on the user
        [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:[result objectForKey:@"id"]
                                 forKey:@"fbId"];
        [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
      }
    }];
  }
}];
```

Then, when you are ready to search for your user's friends, you would issue another request:

```
// Issue a Facebook Graph API request to get your user's friend list
[FBRequestConnection startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // result will contain an array with your user's friends in the "data" key
    NSArray *friendObjects = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSMutableArray *friendIds = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:friendObjects.count];
    // Create a list of friends' Facebook IDs
    for (NSDictionary *friendObject in friendObjects) {
        [friendIds addObject:[friendObject objectForKey:@"id"]];
    }

    // Construct a PFUser query that will find friends whose facebook ids
    // are contained in the current user's friend list.
    PFQuery *friendQuery = [PFUser query];
    [friendQuery whereKey:@"fbId" containedIn:friendIds];

    NSArray *friendUsers = [friendQuery findObjects];
  }
}];
```

Best regards,

Comment: Is this the only way?

Comment: @EricChuang The only way I know.

Comment: I have had some success with this, but was wondering something a little bit different.  Is there a way to make this on Cloud Code?  Something like afterSave on _User it can send a Push to all users on the app who have a friend with matching fbId that their friend has joined?

Comment: @user717452 Yes, you can do it from Cloud Code. I don't know the recipe for this, though. You should search for it's equivalents in the Parse docs.